# Resetting ThreadLocal<T> Value

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I initialize my ThreadLocal with a valueFactory Func.

I would also like to reset the Value back to null on occasion.

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but if I set my threadLocal.Value = null, it still seems to think that threadLocal.IsValueCreated == true.

How can I truly reset the threadlocal so that it will regenerate the Value lazily when it is asked for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.

You could always make it a `ThreadLocal<Lazy<T>>`, and set it to a new `Lazy<T>` whenever you wanted to reset it. If this is something you use more than once, you might want to consider encapsulating it as a `ResettableThreadLocal<T>` or something like that.